# Handle special characters in lua file path (umlauts)

Tags: lua, windows-server-2008-r2, lua-5.1

I have a small lua function to check if a file exists

```
function file_exists( filePath )
    local handler = io.open( filePath )
    if handler then
        io.close( handler )
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

However, this will always return `false` when the file path contains special chars such as German umlauts (äöü). Is there any way around this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to encode file names in Windows default codepage (usually win12xx) instead of UTF-8.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by that? I get my file paths from a different source which initially stores them

Comment: I mean your paths (received from a different source) may be in wrong codepage.  Check it with `yourpath:byte(1,-1)` to guess the encoding.

Comment: yes, they are stored in UTF-8. But I guess there is no way in lua to convert  into a different codepage, is there?

Comment: Of course, there is a way.  What is your Windows codepage? You can determine your codepage from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP` or by running this program in LuaJIT: `f=require"ffi" f.cdef"int GetACP();" print(f.C.GetACP())`

Comment: Accroding to the REG it's 1252. The Lua code you provided did not work "module "ffi" not found")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
utf8_to_cp1252 = (
   function(cp1252_description)
      local unicode_to_1252 = {}
      for code, unicode in cp1252_description:gmatch'\n0x(%x%x)%s+0x(%x+)' do
         unicode_to_1252[tonumber(unicode, 16)] = tonumber(code, 16)
      end
      local undefined = ('?'):byte()
      return
         function (utf8str)
            local pos, result = 1, {}
            while pos <= #utf8str do
               local code, size = utf8str:byte(pos, pos), 1
               if code >= 0xC0 and code < 0xFE then
                  local mask = 64
                  code = code - 128
                  repeat
                     local next_byte = utf8str:byte(pos+size, pos+size) or 0
                     if next_byte >= 0x80 and next_byte < 0xC0 then
                        code, size = (code - mask - 2) * 64 + next_byte, size+1
                     else
                        code, size = utf8str:byte(pos, pos), 1
                     end
                     mask = mask * 32
                  until code < mask
               end
               pos = pos + size
               table.insert(result, 
                  string.char(unicode_to_1252[code] or undefined))
            end
            return table.concat(result)
         end
   end
)[[
download 
http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT
and insert the whole text here:

#
#    Name:     cp1252 to Unicode table
#    Unicode version: 2.0
#    Table version: 2.01
..................................
0xFD    0x00FD  #LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE
0xFE    0x00FE  #LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
0xFF    0x00FF  #LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
]]
```

**Usage:**

```
cp1252_filename = utf8_to_cp1252(your_utf8_filename)
```

Now you can use `cp1252_filename` to invoke `io.open()`, `os.rename()`, `os.execute()` and other functions from standard Lua library.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll give this a try and let you know if this works for me

Comment: while I honestly don't understand the whole magic here this actually works for me :) thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for japanese, russian, and some other language characters.

Comment: @mrg95 - See [this project](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/2458547aa3b9210a8b5f686ac08ecbf0) - it does have support for japanese, russian, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Lua and its tiny standard library is platform neutral and is not aware of correct Windows functions to read full unicode names. You can use [`winapi`](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) module to get some Windows-specific functions for this task. Note that it requires short name generation to be enabled on target disk.

```
local handler = io.open( winapi.short_path(filePath) )
if handler then
    -- etc
end
```

It can also be easily installed through LuaRocks: `luarocks install winapi`.

Comment: I should add that we are using lua as part of another application - which ships the lua component. Could the way to install the lua extension with luarocks work anyway? we have not yet luarocks installed.

Comment: You can simply put all the files in any path that `require` would read from by hand.