# LUA: how to correctly read UFT8 file names and path with accented letters and umlaut?

Tags: windows, utf-8, lua, codepages

Inside a more complex script in LUA, I created the following function, that is supposed to
retrieve the list of all audio files located into a directory, which is specified when the function is called (first parameter).

The function returns a formatted HTML line or a CSV one, based on the value of the 2nd parameter.

If 1, it returns HTML
If 2, it returns CSV

This function works fine unless path and/or file names don't have accented letters or umlauts.
Then fails.

here an exaggerated example, with which I've made tests:

```
J:\PRODUCTION\tüv-ààéérï-utf8\Rendering\tüv-ààéérï-utf8_.wav
```

I did try to implement solution like the one presented here:

[converting UTF-8 string to ASCII in pure LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855842/converting-utf-8-string-to-ascii-in-pure-lua/41859181#comment124002321_41859181)

and here:

[Handle special characters in lua file path (umlauts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717078/handle-special-characters-in-lua-file-path-umlauts)

but unsuccessfully.

Is there a way, in LUA, to get file names and path as they have accented/umlauted characters?

**IMPORTANT:**
the LUA interpreter is not standalone. It's the one built-in the audio application Reaper.
Hence, I can't install some particular LUA extension apart.
So, I need to write some code but I'm totally lost.
[EDIT]
operating system Windows, but i should work also on Mac and Linux as well

```
----------------------------------------------
-- SCAN RENDERED AUDIO
----------------------------------------------
function scandir(directory,format)
  local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
  t = ''
  local f=io.popen('dir '..directory)
    for filename in popen('dir "'..directory..'" /b'):lines() do
      local extension = filename:match("^.+(%..+)$")
      if extension == ".wav" or
         extension == ".mp3" or
         extension == ".flac" or
         extension == ".mov" or
         extension == ".ogg" or
         extension == ".mp4" then
          uriFormat = filename:gsub(" ", "%%20")
          if format == 1 then
            t = t..'<tr class="Rendered"><td>'..directory..'</td><td>'..tostring(filename)..'</td><td><audio controls src="'..directory..'/'..tostring(uriFormat)..'"/></td></tr>'
          elseif format == 2 then
            t = t..directory..','..tostring(filename)..','..directory..tostring(filename)..LF
          end
          i = i + 1
      end
 
    end
  return t
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is converting output of `dir` command to UTF8 string.

Create file `cp.bat` somewhere on your disk:

```
@chcp %1 >nul
```

Replace
`popen('dir "'..`
with
`popen('C:\\path\\to\\cp.bat 65001 <nul & dir "'..`

---

The second problem is converting input parameter `directory` (a UTF-8 string passed to the function `scandir` as argument) to the correct encoding.
`io.popen` expects its argument to be in 1252 codepage.
So, use function `utf8_to_win` from [this script](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f).
Do not forget to set your codepage (1252) at line #11

Comment: what serves to create the empty cp.bat, please?
And: the function you linked to me, is properly converting the umlaut?
About the line 11: the final html page is in UTF8, so I would need to reconvert in UTF8 as well.

Comment: `empty cp.bat` this file must not be empty. it contains 1 line of code. You can create a .txt file and rename it to .bat. `is properly converting the umlaut?` yes

Comment: `i should work also on Mac and Linux` - you should have separate branch of Lua code for windows (with conversions) and for linux (without).  Lua can check the OS by `os.getenv"OS"`

Comment: Ok I'm wiring now the code you suggested. Just do noot commit errors:
1. Is the line of code inside the .bat: @chcp %1 >nul? I suppose yes. Can you please confirm or correct me?
2. There are 2 occurrences of "popen('dir "'..". I think I have to make the changes in both. Right?

Comment: Dir passed to the function: J:\PRODUCTION\tüv-ààéérï-utf8/Rendering
Dir after conversion utf8_to_win(): J:\PRODUCTION\tüv-??éér?-utf8/Rendering
I need to reconvert on UTF8 using win_to_utf8() but I get: J:\TUTORIALS\tüv-??éér?-utf8/Rendering losing the characters

Comment: Sorry my fault. i didn't spot the first line of the code. There is 1250 but in EU we are 1252.
However the filename is not back-convertible. I mean I'm able to convert back the directory but not the filename: J:\TUTORIALS\tüv-ààéérï-utf8/Rendering/?v??-utf8_.wav no clue why

Comment: Yes (on both questions)

Comment: `I'm able to convert back the directory but not the filename` - Check the ANSI codepage of your OS with regedit (see details in github gist comments).  It should match the codepage at line #11.  The letters outside this codepage will be replaced with `?`.

Comment: Line1: local f=io.popen(directory..'\\cp.bat 65001 & dir ')
Line2: for filename in popen('dir "'..directory..'\\cp.bat 65001 & dir /b'):lines() do
it doesn't work as it should
directory = J:J:\TUTORIALS\tüv-ààéérï-utf8/Rendering and the cp.bat is created in it

Comment: Is `directory` a UTF8 or 1252 string?

Comment: Yes the directory name is ok. What's lost is the file name. there I'm lost as well.
But the directory name is not detected by "popen". I pass the already formatted name to the function. While the file name is retrieved from the OS (1252 verified with the suggestion you gave me).
So: now it's getting the file, but I can't rebuild the real name at all, hence the html line, where there is the player, is broken

Comment: `now it's getting the file, but I can't rebuild the real name` - what do you mean?  You receive filename as ready-to-use UTF8 string.  What are you trying to "rebuild"?  You must escape some characters when generating HTML code, but it is a simple task.

Comment: One of the goal of the script, is to retrieve the file name as it is "tüv-ààéérï-utf8_.wav" and create the html statement as seen in the line "if format==1". LUA doesn't retrieve this filename as it supposed to be. It put's strange characters. hence my post here. In fact, even using the script you suggested, I cannot rebuild the correct file name "tüv-ààéérï-utf8_.wav". I think the issue is inside POPEN instruction itself. Hence the html instruction is broken.

Comment: Let's check if the output of io.popen is correct or not.  Please show the result of `print(filename:byte(1,-1))` for the line containing `tüv-ààéérï-utf8_.wav`, exactly as you received it from io.popen

Comment: Please here the output. I've made a screenshot of it, I think it's better: https://i.imgur.com/zClTQh6.png

Comment: I don't see the result of print(filename:byte(1,-1)) on the screenshot.

Comment: As I stated in my opening post, into the "important" note, the LUA is under Reaper. Thus the print() itself prints the output on a pop up as you can see from the screenshot I posted.
The output you see in this screenshot, it's the same I get also in the HTML line. It's consistent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239753/discussion-between-egor-skriptunoff-and-tormy-van-cool).